# Why localhost react different compare to server in PHP programing

Tags: php, localhost, cpanel

My question is look like duplicate but it is not.
Error like

> Notice: Constant BASE_URL already defined in
>   Notice: Undefined variable: nomobile in
>   Notice: Constant imagesize already defined in
>   Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in

But there is no problem in server. and i am using 
PHP version: 5.6.30 both side.

Comment: It seems like php version is same on both sides but code doesn't.

Comment: ya, also i did try. PHP version: 7.1.9. bust same problem.

Comment: I think this is a not problem about php version.

Comment: I was saying that may be code you are using is not same on server & localhost.

Comment: no, it is same code , only database config file and path are different.

Comment: So post some code here where getting these errors.

Comment: there is no problem about code. there is problem with why differ react localhost compare to server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174209/discussion-between-prasanna-mane-and-lovepreet-singh).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: _"there is no problem about code"_ - How can you be that sure? We're not and to be able to help you, we need to see it and get an explanation about the setup. If not, then there's nothing anyone can do to help you since we're totally in the dark over here.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs - Considering that the OP is actually posting output from error reporting, I doubt that link will be of much help.

Comment: because  code well work in server.

Comment: It can still be the code, depending on how you include different files etc. It might not take different environments into account and so forth. Either way, this isn't a "general issue" so it has to do with something that you haven't told us about.

Comment: I 100% with you.  But same error why not showing in server? you mean server have more features?

Comment: Error is always error is does matter where you running code?

Comment: _"you mean server have more features?"_ - You do realize that asking us is pretty pointless? As I stated, you _haven't given us anything to go on._ We have _no idea_ what your set up _or_ your code looks like. It's _impossible_ for us to know why this is. I'm voting to close this question for lack of info...

Comment: @Magnus  I think error reporting is disabled on his server, so he just think there is not notices

Comment: @NobbyNobbs - That's a really good point! Didn't think of that... You should have just have clarified that in your first comment :-) That's most likely the case...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i know you dont have copy about code.but my question still the same why not showing error in server side. evern code and php version is same.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs i will check thank you.

Comment: @NobbyNobbs it is 100% work, Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

This is error disable in server so server cannot show error.

[For more information](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/troubleshoot-php-errors)